# Hanging heavy mirror on brick wall

Tags: screws

What size screw or bolt do I need to hang 55lb framed mirror on internal single brick wall? Two fixtures allowed on mirror back. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"[Masonry sleeve anchors](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Red-Head-3-8-in-x-1-7-8-in-Hex-Sleeve-Anchor-25-Pack-11279/204402234)" are used by electricians to hang electrical boxes and other equipment on brick/block walls.  They are [plenty strong](https://www.confast.com/products/technical-info/concrete-sleeve-anchor.aspx) for your need.

Or you could use [Tapcons](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Tapcon-1-4-in-x-1-1-4-in-Hex-Washer-Head-Concrete-Anchors-75-Pack-24315/100086102) (for performance see [shear strength](http://www.tapcon.com/documents/charts_performancetables_maxiset_v0-0_cp.pdf)), but I find the sleeve anchors to be more versatile and they are stronger.

Either of those solutions is way strong enough to handle your mirror.

Comment: Drill into the brick, not the mortar.